# How to refer to those fully-equipped houses people let to university students?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have a friend who rents in an one-story house. Just your common house: there's a living room, a kitchen, and three rooms (all of them occupied by university students).

It something like this from the outside:

[image: A tropical-style house with a wraparound porch supported by rough tree-trunk pillars. A small dormer window is just visible at the back of the house. The house is surrounded with palm trees and eucalyptus trees, and there's a brick-paved driveway or walkway visible in the foreground. All you can see of the house itself is one big picture window; there's no way to tell how large the house is, or what sort of layout it has. (In other words, it doesn't seem to illustrate the question at all.)]

How would you call this kind of building?

Comment: The question would be worded better and more naturally if it had the word *fully* instead of full, as well as the word *let* instead of rent. See http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/let_3

Comment: I have no idea what that picture is supposed to illustrate. It doesn't show anything about what sort of house this is, or what sort of people might possibly live in it. All I can tell is that it's located in a tropical climate, and doesn't look like any home I'd expect to find in North America.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the UK, it is most common for any premises rented out to students to be referred to as as "student-lets".

Answer (score 1):

I've heard people say "house-share".  As in "Do you live in the dorms? No, I have a house-share."

Some universities have options like this on campus, owned by the school, and then there's probably a school-specific name for them (e.g. Vassar College has what they call ["Town Houses"](http://residentiallife.vassar.edu/residence-halls/halls/tathsc.html)).

Answer (score 1):

A "furnished" home or apartment is provided with furniture (and often linens, dishes, and other accoutrements), often at minimal additional cost.